# Adding Android Google PlusOneButton to layout causes compilation error

Tags: android, button, implementation

I would like to add the google+ button to my app. I followed this instruction:
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend

I can neither implement the class **PlusOneButton** nor the the xml-tag: `<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton/>`

*Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton*

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/custom_margin_top_bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/custom_margin_top_bottom">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nachrichtTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton

            android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

Add to **Gradle**:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
```

To your **layout.xml** you add button:

```
<com.google.android.gms.plus.PlusOneButton
    xmlns:plus="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.plus"
    android:id="@+id/plus_one_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    plus:size="standard"
    plus:annotation="inline" />
```

At last in your **Activity** where you have PlusOneButton:

```
    PlusOneButton plusOneButton =(PlusOneButton) findViewById(R.id.plus_one_button);

    plusOneButton.initialize(URL, 0);
```

Comment: If I dont like the design of the button and want to use a regular one. how can i add the behavior?